# Center MUI model for different screen sizes

Tags: typescript, material-ui, modal-dialog, tsx

I am trying to center my modal box directly in the center of the screen. The issue is that the box is off center when screen changes different sizes. I tried doing top:50% and left: 50% but that hasn't centered the box at all

```css
 centeredBox: {
    width: "400px",
    height: "380px",
    top: "50%",
    left: "50%",
    position: "absolute",
    background: "#FFFFFF",
    boxShadow: "0px 0.5px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)",
    borderRadius: "6px",
  },
```

```
    <Modal open={props.openModal} onClose={props.closeModal}>
      <div className={centeredBox}></div
    </Modal>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
centeredBox: {
    position: absolute,
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    margin: auto;
    width: "400px",
    height: "380px",
}
```